# getting an amazon ec2 instance similar (in terms of performance) to my desktop PC

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, intel, ram, scientific-computing

I am a bit puzzled by the performance of amazon ec2 instances.

Specifically, I would like to know whether I can obtain an amazon EC2 windows instance that is close to my current desktop pc.

My desktop pc has 36 gb RAM (1600 mhz), i7 3770K and a fast SSD drive (kingston hyperX).

My computational needs are simple: I use a lot of statistical programs (such as R or Stata) which essentially

1) read the data from the hard disk

2) store the data in the RAM

3) perform computations (**most of which can take advantage of up to 4 cores**)

What do you think? Can I get an equal or greater performance?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the AWS EC2 [Instance Types Matrix](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

- CPU: They use Intel Xeon, should be better than your desktop i7 cpu. Also the vCPU number could be up to 32.
- RAM: Memory could be up to 32G.
- SSD: Mostly SSD. You could even add extra SSD storage.

It's likely to gain better performance than your desktop pc if using 
Compute Optimized instance type c3.4xlarge or higher.